# How to insert inline assembly instruction by using llvm pass in SPEC CPU 2006 benchmarks

Tags: c++, clang, inline-assembly, clang++, llvm-ir

The summary of what I want to do is as follows.

1. Detect {for loop's start,end point} in SPEC CPU 2006 benchmark's source code
2. Insert inline assembly instruction that didn't exist before (ex. 0xFF570000)

So, i made LLVM pass that functions i wrote above. And build the benchmarks by LLVM Pass.
It works in benchmarks that use C language (ex.bzip2) but in C++ language benchmarks(ex. namd) occurs error.

I don't know why is it C and not C++. how can i solve this problem?.I changed the LLVM version but made the same error.

**Here is my Pass.cpp code**

```
using namespace llvm;
namespace {
struct Hello : public LoopPass {
static char ID;
Hello() : LoopPass(ID) {}
virtual bool runOnLoop(Loop *L, LPPassManager &LPM) override {
    BasicBlock* header = L->getHeader();

    IRBuilder<> IRB_start(&(*header->begin()));
    Module* M_start = header->getModule();
    LLVMContext& ctxt_start= M_start->getContext();
    Type* voidTy_start = Type::getVoidTy(ctxt_start);
    FunctionType* funcTy_start = FunctionType::get(voidTy_start, false);
    InlineAsm *start_inst_asm = InlineAsm::get(funcTy_start, StringRef(".long 0xFF570000"), StringRef("~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"), true);
    ArrayRef<Value*> Args = None;
    CallInst *start_inst = IRB_start.CreateCall(start_inst_asm, Args);
    start_inst->addAttribute(AttributeList::FunctionIndex, Attribute::NoUnwind);

    SmallVector<BasicBlock*, 8> exit_blocks;
    L->getExitBlocks(exit_blocks);
    for(int i = 0; i < exit_blocks.size(); i++){
          IRBuilder<> IRB_end(&(*exit_blocks[i]->begin()));
          Module* M_end = exit_blocks[i]->getModule();
          LLVMContext& ctxt_end= M_end->getContext();
          Type* voidTy_end = Type::getVoidTy(ctxt_end);
          FunctionType* funcTy_end = FunctionType::get(voidTy_end, false);
          InlineAsm *end_inst_asm = InlineAsm::get(funcTy_end, StringRef(".long 0xFF580000"), StringRef("~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}"), true);

          ArrayRef<Value*> Args = None;
          CallInst *end_inst = IRB_end.CreateCall(end_inst_asm, Args);
          end_inst->addAttribute(AttributeList::FunctionIndex, Attribute::NoUnwind);
     }
return false;


  }

}; // end of struct Hello
}  // end of anonymous namespace

char Hello::ID = 0;

static void registerHello(const PassManagerBuilder &,
                          legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
  PM.add(new Hello());
}
static RegisterStandardPasses
  RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                  registerHello);
```

**And config file code is**

```
CXX             =/usr/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --gcc-toolchain=/home/bryankim/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/ --sysroot /home/bryankim/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc -std=c++03 -Xclang -load -Xclang /home/ksj930/c_test/llvm_pass_for_loop_6.0.0/Bryan_pass/libLLVMBryan_pass.so
```

**runspec code**

```
runspec -config=aarch64_llvm_xcompile.cfg -action=build namd
```

**Lastly, here is my error**

```
1.  <eof> parser at end of file
2.  Per-module optimization passes
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module 'ComputeList.C'.
4.  Running pass 'Combine redundant instructions' on function '@_ZN11ComputeListD2Ev'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: aarch64--linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/ComputeList-fe1d87.cpp
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /tmp/ComputeList-fe1d87.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg:
```

How can i solve this error. please help me

Comment: You have a segfault. The usual procedure is to run your code in a debugger and find out which line segfaults. Have you done that?

Comment: OR use valgrind in a debug build will give you some backtraces too

Comment: @arnt: Thanks for your answer. I tried to debug by gdb but i don't know how to apply '-g' command in my code.  Can you tell me how to debug using gdb in runspec?

Comment: You mean to pass command-line options in gdb? If your usual way to start the program is `foo -b ar`, then `gdb foo` followed by `run -b ar` will do.

Comment: @Jellyboy: Thank you. i'll study about valgrind and try it

Comment: @Jin Are you using cmake to build your code or you are compiling it by hand? If you are compiling by hand, just add `-g` to the gcc command line as in `g++ -g ...`. If you are using cmake, do a debug build as in `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug ...`